How to get an array object value using Byteman Tool?
I am using below piece of code:
I am able to find the value of trade id using Byteman by the same method, but Not able to get the value for measure[0].
PS: I am able to get the value using java- x[0].getValue. But I need this using Byteman.
            `final NewArray[] x= new NewArray[1];
    x[0] = new NewArray(NewArray.NPV);
    

    ETOtrade.price(trade, new Datetime(), env, x);`
    

Any instance method to get the array object value using Byteman?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
